# JPA Error Don't Change Reference to Collection Even Though it's not Being Explicitly Changed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to know how to get rid of this error, but at this point I’d settle for why I’m getting it.

The error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : com.asdf.data.entity.jpa.impl.Account.authorizations
```

The implicated method near the top of the stack trace:

```
    @Override
    public Account save(Account account) {
        if (account == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String normailzedUserDN = UserDNParseUtil.normalizeUserDN(account.getUserDn());
            cacheConfig.evictSingleCacheValue("accountCache", normailzedUserDN);
            
            Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
            session.save(account);
            
            String query = "select a from Account a where a.isActive IS TRUE and a.userDn = :userDn";
            
            TypedQuery<Account> q = em.createQuery(query, Account.class);
            q.setParameter("userDn", account.getUserDn());
            
            account = q.getSingleResult(); // This is line 80, so the error occurs here
            
            return account;
        }
    }
```

Relevant lines from Account class:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Authorization> authorizations;

    @Valid
    public Set<Authorization> getAuthorizations() {
        return authorizations;
    }

    public void setAuthorizations(final Set<Authorization> authorizations) {
        if (this.authorizations==null) {
            this.authorizations=new HashSet<Authorization>();
        } else {
            this.authorizations.clear();
        }
        this.authorizations.addAll(authorizations);
    }
```

Nowhere in our code are we explicitly changing the reference to the authorizations field, and the setter is never called, at least according to the breakpoint I set. So, is this a JPA / Reflection thing that’s occurring on retrieval of the account that’s setting the field? Obviously, removing the orphanRemoval attribute from the field fixes it, but I don’t necessarily want to do that, as authorizations without an account make no sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've got the JSONIgnore annotation on the collection, but with the orphanRemoval=true option on it too - how are you handling deserialization from JSON and merging that object into the DB if that collection isn't included? Your issue, despite where the error is thrown, is due to the save call. JPA operations are just delayed until there is a need to synchronize to the database, which is on the query to make sure it flushes any changes that might affect the query results. If you look back on the instances passed in to this method, you might hit your break point or see a collection change.

Comment: If you use the em.merge(account) and return what is returned from that call (instead of re-querying what must be the same instance), do you get the same issue?

Comment: No, I don't get the error with merge and just returning that. Interesting. I'll have to see if that breaks anything else or introduces any degradation in performance because this code is called so frequently. Regarding the JSONIgnore, I believe that's used by the API so that particular field isn't included in the response.

Comment: Merge without the extra query should improve performance (though you may want to force a flush to get exactly the same behavior), and I suspect this is a Hibernate native api only validation as changing collections is perfectly legal with JPA. JSONIgnore also affect deserialization - so make sure you correct for this collection being null/empty if using JSON to get the data back for changes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't even have a setter for authorizations.

If you want to keep it, your code should look like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
// Initialize here to prevent NPE when someone is calling getAuthorizations().add()
private Set<Authorization> authorizations = new HashSet<>();

@Valid
public Set<Authorization> getAuthorizations() {
    return authorizations;
}

public void setAuthorizations(final Set<Authorization> authorizations) {
    this.authorizations = authorizations;
}
```

But I would suggest not to expose a setter.

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
// Initialize here to prevent NPE when someone is calling getAuthorizations().add()
private Set<Authorization> authorizations = new HashSet<>();

@Valid
public Set<Authorization> getAuthorizations() {
    return authorizations;
}

public void addAuthorizations(final Authorization authorization) {
    this.authorizations.add(authorization);
}

public void removeAuthorizations(final Authorization authorization) {
    this.authorizations.remove(authorization);
}
```

Comment: Agree. There is code elsewhere that depends on it, so I would have to refactor a few other classes. But that wouldn't fix this issue if it's not being called, or am I missing something?

Comment: This will fix the issue. because the problem ist this line  this.authorizations=new HashSet<Authorization>();